# Convergence pw if converges in Lp space

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, smooth-manifolds

Let $p\in[1,\infty]$ be given.

If $f$ and $g$ are non-negative analytic functions such that the following holds:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\frac{\partial^ig(t)}{\partial^it}|^pdt=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\frac{\partial^if(t)}{\partial^it}|^pdt
\end{equation}

then does this imply that $f=g$ pointwise?

Comment: What you mean by "converge"? do you mean that their norms are the same?

Comment: Sorry I corrected the question, I wrote down the wrong thing.

Comment: This equation that you wrote is trivial. Shouldn't it be $g$ on one side and $f$ on the other?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Here is a counterexample: $g(x)=f(x+a)$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $a\ne0$.